# C - Incompatible pointer type assignment: why is it a warning?

Tags: c

I'm looking at K&R 2nd edition, which says (in section 5.4):

> It is not legal to [..] except for void *, to assign a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type without a cast.

However, both gcc and clang just raise a warning, but not a compiler error, when doing this:

```
int *ip;
char *cp;

ip = cp;
```

I'm not seeing anything on the gcc manual stating that this is a default compiler extension. Using a C++ compiler does raise a compilation error.

Notice that the book seems to contradict itself in section A6.6 where it says

> A pointer to one type may be converted to a pointer to another type.

though I'm giving it the benefit of the doubt since it may be referring to using an explicit cast to convert from a pointer type to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *ip;
char *cp;

ip = cp;
```

The assignment is a *constraint violation*, meaning that a conforming compiler must emit a diagnostic, just as it must do for a syntax error. (See http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1 for the requirements on simple assignments.) That diagnostic can be a non-fatal warning. The C standard never requires code to be rejected unless it has a `#error` directive. It doesn't refer to code as "legal" or "illegal".

gcc will treat it as a fatal error if you compile with, for example, `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. Note that gcc is not a fully conforming C compiler by default, though its behavior in this case is conforming.

The assignment would be legal with a cast (an explicit conversion):

```
ip = (int*)cp;
```

but it might cause undefined behavior if the value of `cp` is indeterminate or if the conversion results in an invalid `int*` value (due to alignment, for example).

The description in K&R is correct, though worded a bit informally. It says:

> It is not legal to [..] except for void *, to assign a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type without a cast.
>   which is true if by "legal" they meant "not violating a constraint or syntax rule". The C standard itself doesn't use the word "legal", but saying that something is a constraint violation is as close as it gets to saying something is illegal.

And yes, this:

> A pointer to one type may be converted to a pointer to another type.
>   does refer to conversion using a cast -- or without a cast in the case of converting to and from `void*`.

(My personal preference would be for syntax errors and constraint violations to be treated as fatal errors, but most compilers are relatively lax by default. This is likely for historical reasons. In very early versions of the language, assigning a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type without a cast was valid, and there was never a good time to break old code by rejecting it.)

Comment: Thanks, I added the link just before you posted your comment.

Comment: Right, makes sense.

That doesn't take away the fact that K&R is wrong, and also contradicts itself. Not surprising.

Comment: @Martin K&R is neither wrong nor self-contradictory, just slightly informal. I've updated my answer to address that point.

Comment: K&R do certainly use the term "illegal" to mean "doesn't compile". Here, have an example from section 2.7:

"Expressions that might lose information [...] may draw a warning, but they are not illegal."

Comment: @Martin That's consistent with what I said. A conforming compiler *must* issue a diagnostic (which may or may not be fatal) for any violation of a constraint or syntax rule. A compiler *may* issue a non-fatal warning for anything it likes. I think if you assume that "illegal" means "violating a constraint or syntax rule", you'll *probably* find that K&R is internally consistent and consistent with the standard. (The standard doesn't require a distinction between warnings for constraint or syntax violations and warnings that are at the whim of the compiler, which is IMHO unfortunate.)

Comment: The standard doesn't, but do you honestly believe that K&R were thinking about "diagnostics" and "constraints violations"? Of course not. They made a clear distinction between a "warning" and something that's "illegal", i.e. doesn't compile. Look at the "hello world" example in 1.1, they clearly state that if you introduce a newline in the middle of a string "the C compiler will produce an error message". By your logic, that's the one and only case where the compilation should fail?

Comment: @Martin: K&R2 isn't the standard, and doesn't have the same rigor that the standard attempts to achieve. Compilers typically do produce fatal errors for syntax errors, so when they say that a newline in a string literal will cause the C compiler to produce an error message, that's not guaranteed by the standard, but it's pretty much universally true. (And even that assumes that "error message" doesn't include non-fatal warnings.) And I'm pretty sure the authors knew the language.

Comment: You're beating around the bush here. My point is that K&R saying that something is "illegal" means the compilation will fail. K&R says that this assignment is illegal (which is wrong), then says it's not (which contradicts the previous statement). You first played word games, then reverted back to saying "well, K&R isn't the standard, so you can't expect them to be rigorous". This isn't the book being slightly ambiguous (as they do multiple times), but just flat-out wrong. Also, keep in mind that K&R 1st edition *was*, in effect, the standard.

Comment: Since the standard doesn't use or define the terms "legal" and "illegal", using those words informally in a book that's essentially a tutorial is not wrong. It does not contradict itself; the statement that "A pointer to one type may be converted to a pointer to another type." is both correct and consistent with what it said before. It's in the reference manual section of the book, which also clearly states the requirements for assignment expressions (A7.17), making it clear that a cast is required for most pointer conversions. Where does K&R equate "illegal" with compilation failure?

Comment: What else could "illegal" possibly mean, especially when they explicitly distinguish between "drawing a warning" and "being illegal"? Furthermore, why are we even talking about the standard in the first place? We're discussing the book, which, for some time, _was_ the standard, so it's not just a "tutorial". Yes, I did mention that the assignment part may be referring to a cast (re-read my question), and that, in that sense, the book may not be contradicting itself.

At this point you're just stuck in denial. Again, following your logic, only the newline case should emit an error.